# Codeigniter Form to Html

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I have placed the below codeigniter code and i want this code to be written in html .Pls help me to do this.

```
<?php

echo form_open('contact/create_member');

echo form_input('name', set_value('name', ' Name'));
echo form_input('email_address', set_value('email_address', 'Email Address'));
echo form_input('college_name', set_value('college_name', 'college_name'));
echo form_input('address', set_value('address', 'address'));
echo form_input('phone_number', set_value('phone_number', 'phone_number'));
echo form_textarea('message', set_value('message', 'message'));
echo form_submit('submit', 'Submit');

?>
```

Comment: I want to convert this codeigniter form into Html Form.

Comment: take a look here http://ellislab.com/codeigniter%20/user-guide/helpers/form_helper.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<form action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>contact/create_number" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
    <input type="text" name="name" value="Name" />
    <input type="text" name="email_address" value="Email Address" />
    <input type="text" name="college_name" value="college_name" />
    <input type="text" name="address" value="address" />
    <input type="text" name="phone_number" value="phone_number" />
    <textarea name="message">phone_number</textarea>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

For your form action in html, you have to use the `base_url` of your application defined in `config.php` because that's how `echo form_open('contact/create_member');` creates the action url.

If you are not sure how to use the native form_helper of codeigniter, please kindly skim this documenation. [FORM HELPER CODEIGNTER](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/form_helper.html)

Answer (score 0):

You should load the form helper in the autoload or where ever your want.

```
$this->load->helper('form');
```

And the code will will be converted into html execution after sever side